# trying to sort on a reference property of an entity but don't want to sort on object but a ppty of the object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have done a query and I want to then order it by a reference property attribute - can I temporarily add a field in the results of my query and add in the attribute to sort it before I send it to the template?

```
q = LetterTable.all().order('votes)
```

but then I want to take the q results above and sort on a property of LetterTable called "Person".  However, 'person' is a reference to an instance on the PersonTable, so I don't want the reference object, I want to sort by person.name.  How can I do this?

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not stright out of the box.  There's some page in the GAE docs that describe how queries work.  Essentially your entities are indexed by property, and when you run a query, it just looks through the index.

In your case, the index contains the reference property and not the PersonTable entity it refers to, so the index doesn't have person.name.

The appropriate way to do this in App Engine is to denormalize.  That means storing an extra copy of some data you need, in this case, you'd store a copy of person.name inside your LetterTable entity.  Then you can query and sort on that name.

```
class LetterTable(db.Model):
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
    person_name = db.StringProperty()
```

This method certainly has its drawbacks, the primary being keeping data in sync (ie, if a person changes their name, you'll have to find all LetterTable instances that refer to that person, and change all the denormalized names).

Comment: Thanks - hmmm. yes - don't like it that I have to do it that way but I guess that's the limitation